# Messages app stopped working

Tags: messages

**Your Apple ID "xxx" can't be used to set up iMessage at this time.**

iTunes and Xcode work without complaint.

I refuse to give them $20 to have someone push a couple buttons and force the servers to recognize my ID when it's used from a particular device. It is not something that can be solved from my end, and it is not reasonable to charge for the "service" of letting me use my own computer.

What contact method will allow me to have this resolved without paying an unnecessary fee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Ignore AppleCare

Go to [Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.action)

More Products & Services > Apple ID > Other Apple ID Topics > Messages and Apple ID
Your Customer Code is the most useful piece of information.

This error is a result of the system assuming unauthorized access and locking down access to the service. Security is inconvenient.

Comment: I'm sure most people figure this out and just quietly leave the forums, but it's good to have a clear guide, no?